# Web API 404.0 Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I have gone through a large number of possible solutions to my issue but I still cannot get the Web API to work properly on my new development machine.  Both my old working development machine and the new one are running Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 64-Bit.  The Production website, running on Windows Server 2012, works just fine but I cannot get my new computer to resolve a web api call.  The call is:

```
http://localhost/clientsite/data/getdata?key=thiskey
```

I ensured that WebDAV was not installed, installed all of the various Web API components and MVC 4 and I am currently using the following config entries:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Does anybody know what I am missing?  Thanks!

Comment: Same solution as before or did you just implement the same method?

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly - ended up I cannot read my own routing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a stupid error on my part but hopefully this might help others.  In my routing table, I have routeTemplate: ads/{controller}/{id}:

That means that the URL above actually needs to be:

```
http://localhost/clientsite/data/ads/getdata?key=thiskey
```